# Getting error in cocapod installation CryptoSwift

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods, sha, cryptoswift

i installed a pod successfully "cryptoSwift' to get sha-2 in my xcode project using swift2. but after pod installation when i build project it shows me a lot of error in pod files. why i am getting this error. what's i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: i want to generate sha-2 of strings in app

Comment: terminal show a message that successfully installed pod. also it shows in pod file. but when i build the project it give errors in AES module. "no such directory found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no such thing as "sha-2" exaxctly which hash is really need is not clear. Assuming sha-2 means a [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) series hash function the common choices are SHA-256 and SHA-512.

> Example using Common Crypoto (Swift2)

```
func sha256(string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }
    return digest
}
```

Test

```
let testString = "testString"
let testHash = sha256(testString)
print("testHash: \(testHash)")

let testHashNSData = NSData(bytes:testHash, length:testHash.count)
print("testHashNSData: \(testHashNSData)")

let testHashBase64 = testHashNSData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
print("testHashBase64: \(testHashBase64)")
```

Output:

```
testHash: [74, 207, 11, 57, 217, 196, 118, 103, 9, 163, 104, 159, 85, 58, 192, 26, 181, 80, 84, 95, 250, 69, 68, 223, 192, 178, 206, 168, 47, 186, 2, 163]
testHashNSData: <4acf0b39 d9c47667 09a3689f 553ac01a b550545f fa4544df c0b2cea8 2fba02a3>
testHashBase64: Ss8LOdnEdmcJo2ifVTrAGrVQVF/6RUTfwLLOqC+6AqM=
```

> Example using Common Crypoto (Swift3)

```
func sha256(string: String) -> Data? {
    let messageData = string.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
    var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in
        messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
            CC_SHA256(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }
    return digestData
}
```

Test

```
let testString = "testString"
let testHash = sha256(string:testString)
print("testHash: \(testHash!.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")

let testHashBase64 = testHash!.base64EncodedString()
print("testHash: \(testHasBase64)")
```

Output:

```
testHash: 4acf0b39d9c4766709a3689f553ac01ab550545ffa4544dfc0b2cea82fba02a3  
testHashBase64: Ss8LOdnEdmcJo2ifVTrAGrVQVF/6RUTfwLLOqC+6AqM=
```

Note: Add to your Bridging Header:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```